# jQuery .on("click") not registering for dynamic content on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have found many answers to each half of my problem (registering click events on dynamic content, and registering click events on mobile), but none seem to satisfy both. The problem:

```
$(document).on("click", ".element", function() {
    // do something
});
```

.element is dynamically added. This works just fine on desktop browsers, however the click event is not registered on mobile devices for whatever reason.

I am aware that I could use **touchstart** or **touchend** instead of **click**, but that would be undesirable as it would complicate scrolling significantly. Note that using **click** works just fine for static content, but breaks when I attempt to apply it on dynamic content...that is the part that truly baffles me.

Any assistance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe a bug in the version of jQuery you're using? Can you provide what version you're using?

Comment: Have you tried [vclick](https://api.jquerymobile.com/vclick/)? I ran into a similar issue and this fixed it for me

Comment: I suppose it could be a bug, I am using jQuery version 2.1.3. I'll look into vclick and let you know the result. Thanks!

Comment: I would suspect a bug in whatever browser you are using before I'd suspect a bug in jquery.  Try your code in various chrome-emulation modes to see if you can pin down when it works and when it doesn't.

Comment: vclick solved the problem! However, this was only possible because I was already using jQuery Mobile for other reasons. I would still be interested to see if there was a solution to this problem that didn't require using jQuery Mobile. Zacran, feel free to post your answer below and I will accept it as the answer. :)

Comment: @roippi Interestingly enough, I have tried this in many different chrome-emulated modes, and they all work just fine. It's when I try this on my own mobile devices (iPhone 3G, 4S, 6+, and a few versions of the Nexus phone...can't remember which) that it breaks.